# Using ogr2ogr to convert Natural Earth data to Polar Stereographic projection

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, shapefile, ogr2ogr

I’m trying to build some maps of the North Pole area for my website. I’ve flown over it a few times and want to make a map of the flight paths I took. As you can see, a normal Mapbox map doesn't look so great for these polar routes:

[image]

I want a map like this, which I’ve recently learned is called a Polar Stereographic projection.

[image]

And I want to put it in a Mapbox map. Mapbox only supports Mercator projections, so if you want to work with different projections, they need to be cast back to Mercator somehow (I know this is tacky/hacky).

How can I do the following with GDAL/`ogr2ogr`:

- Get Natural Earth Shapefiles
- Transform to a Polar Steerograph projection like `ESPG:3995`
- Make those coordinates work on a Mercator projected map like Mapbox uses
- Get GeoJSON of the shapefile to go into Mapbox Studio with and build a map?

---

Previous research I’ve done:

I found [an old post on the Mapbox blog](https://blog.mapbox.com/mapping-arctic-sea-ice-in-a-polar-projection-a8fd68a03c53) about doing something like this, but the `gdal` commands are outlined generally rather than written out, and the [associated Github repo](https://github.com/ajashton/polarmap) runs all the shapefile changes with Postgres/PostGIS which is overkill, I’m just trying to run a few `ogr2ogr` commands to transform the shape file into gsojson.

I tried a few `ogr2ogr` commands with `t_srs`, `a_srs`, `s_srs`, but my geojson always comes out like this:

```
"geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -6607704.23424893990159, 2768583.037965904921293 ], [ -6606072.226559722796082, 2767507.039690425619483 ],
```

Where the coordinates appear to be in https://epsg.io/3995 format, but since they’re not between -180 and 180, Mapbox can’t process them (I’m failing to get this file converted back to Mercator format I think)

I also found the [Dirty Reprojectors app](https://devseed.com/dirty-reprojectors-app/), but it doesn’t have data in Polar Stereographic projections, presumably because D3 doesn’t support that projection transformation.

Comment: Web mercator is usually cut off at 85 N, so I don't think this will work

Comment: I can be wrong but you may need some *'Azimuthal equidistant projection'*.